# SQL injection? CHAR(45,120,49,45,81,45)

Tags: sql-injection

I just saw this come up in our request logs. What were they trying to achieve?

The full request string is:

```
properties?page=2side1111111111111 UNION SELECT CHAR(45,120,49,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,50,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,51,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,52,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,53,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,54,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,55,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,56,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,57,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,48,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,49,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,50,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,51,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,52,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,53,45,81,45),CHAR(45,120,49,54,45,81,45) -- /*
```

Edit: As a google search didn't return anything useful I wanted to ask the question for people who encounter the same thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is just a test for injection. If an attacker can see xQs in the output then they'll know injection is possible.

There is no "risk" from this particular query.

A developer should pay no attention to whatever injection mechanisms, formats or meanings - these are none of his business.

There is only **one** cause for for all the infinite number of injections - an **improperly formatted query.** As long as your queries are properly formatted then SQL injections are not possible. Focus on your queries rather than methods of SQL injection.

Comment: "A developer should pay no attention to whatever injection mechanisms, formats or meanings - these are none of his business." - Can you elaborate? To me that sounds like I shouldn't care about SQL injection at all. Or place all my trust into whatever framework I use.

Comment: Yes, yes. That's it - you shouldn't.

Comment: Thats madness! If advise people to think like that then why did you write https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql ?

Comment: The very purpose of this library is indeed a proper formatting. While "Safety" mentioned there has a wider meaning - the query is safe from whatever errors caused by improperly formatted literals (including injections but not aimed to).

Comment: Ah okay - so you mean check that your queries are correct and dont care about mechanisms that exploit them. That makes sense.

Comment: Yes. By the way, using a placeholder to represent *every* dynamically added query part is the only way.

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about SQL injection because your user facing code should not allow it. It should be executing stored procedures and passing in parameters. Stored procedures do not care what the user sends in. It's interpreted as data, not code, regardless of quotes or strings or special characters or any other tricks.

Comment: FWIW, this does identity the server type as MySQL, since MySQL char() accepts a variable number of parameters, while SQL Server only accepts one.

Comment: What is the meaning of `xQs` in this answer?

Answer (score 7):

The `Char()` function interprets each value as an integer and returns a string based on given the characters by the code values of those integers. With `Char()`, NULL values are skipped. The function is used within Microsoft SQL Server, Sybase, and MySQL, while `CHR()` is used by RDBMSs.

SQL's `Char()` function comes in handy when (for example) `addslashes()` for PHP is used as a precautionary measure within the SQL query. Using `Char()` removes the need of quotation marks within the injected query.

An example of some PHP code vulnerable to an SQL injection using `Char()` would look similar to the following:

```
$uname = addslashes( $_GET['id'] );
$query = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ' . $id;
```

While `addslashes()` has been used, the script fails properly sanitize the input as there is no trailing quotation mark. This could be exploited using the following SQL injection string to load the `/etc/passwd` file:

Source: http://hakipedia.com/index.php/SQL_Injection#Char.28.29

Comment: Nice intro to injection but doesn't really answer the question, which is "what was that _specific_ SQL trying to acheive?"

Comment: I am interested in both the specific SQL they were trying to execute, but also how this could work. As a google search didn't return anything useful I wanted to start a discussion for people who could be at risk.

Comment: @roo, discussions are not really what SO is for. If you're stating you want to know how the current attack would work (and it appears that is the case here), that's another matter. But the desire to start a discussion is likely to get questions closed and deleted.

Comment: @paxdiablo - Fair point, discussion was the wrong word. I raised the question because I didn't know what this query was trying to do and google didn't have the answer. I knew that SO was the best place to get an answer and have the largest reach if it was something important.